# Sublime Text 3 alternative to use on ARM Linux?

Tags: text-editor, ide, raspberry-pi, sublime-text

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3 to code,at the moment,and I'm not being very lucky on my quest to find an alternative to Sublime Text 3. I tried Vim, but didn't like it that much. Geany felt a little dull to me. Not that much personalization, you know. I'm using CodeAnywhere, but I can't modify local files directly with it.I need an editor capable of displaying 3 or 4 rows of code,with code collapsing(to ease navigation through code), auto-completion and syntax highlighting for C++,Python,HTML,CSS,Go and Lua. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like a private beta for the ARM build started end of July (maybe we got Apple to thank for this?) - https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/arm-build/5882/88

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try out [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) which is an open source IDE that supports all the languages you specified with the help of extensions. I have used it on Mac, Linux and Windows and it is a great IDE with full debugging and Git support.

There are ARM builds available [here](https://code.headmelted.com/) for Linux distros.

Answer (score 1):

My editor-of-choice for Linux, OSX, and Windows (yes, it works equally well on all three) is:

### [Textadept](https://foicica.com/textadept/)

[image: Textadept]

The four specific criteria are **all supported by Textadept**:

- displaying 3 or 4 rows of code,
- with code collapsing (to ease navigation through code),
- auto-completion and
- syntax highlighting

In addition, it is blazingly fast, readily extensible, but has a myriad of other features that mean (in my case!) extending isn't really required.

Support is excellent: the developer is highly responsive, remarkably patient, and updates Textadept regularly. It is also well documented. And for personalizing, there are loads of themes in the [Base16 collection](http://chriskempson.github.io/base16/) maintained by [Robert Gieseke on Github](https://github.com/rgieseke/textadept-themes).

Comment: Is there a Linux ARM version that runs on Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Long time since this was posted, but it works fine on the RasPi - you'll need to compile from source, and there's a couple of libraries to install, but very good!

Answer (score 1):

## Atom

Looks like the [Atom.io text editor](https://atom.io/faq) can be [installed on Raspberry Pi as discussed](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/55031/13889) on the [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/). Atom is a modern GUI text editor that includes line-collapsing and support for syntax coloring for various languages.

Atom is built from JavaScript-based technologies, and so is amenable to porting across platforms.

## Pico, nano, and such

Your Raspberry Pi’s Linux almost certainly supports non-GUI text editors such as [Pico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pico_(text_editor)) or [nano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano).

Comment: Dear Down-Voter: Please leave a criticism along with your vote.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is **[CudaText](http://www.uvviewsoft.com/cudatext/)**, it is now ported for Raspberry Pi 3. It is free, gratis (Open Source, licensed under [Mozilla Public License 2.0](https://github.com/Alexey-T/CudaText/blob/master/license.txt)). Many features are similar to features of ST3, e.g. command palette (F1 here). And CudaLint plugin exists.

[image: CudaText on RPi]

Answer (score 0):

Spacemacs is in advanced beta and is highly customisable. Org-mode (in Spacemacs) has excellent folding capability. I don't use it for code, but I believe most users do. It handles many languages/code bases well. [Slant](http://www.slant.co/versus/69/5983/~spacemacs_vs_codelite-ide) users give Spacemacs high marks compared to codelite and Visual Studio Code. The keybindings are very intuitive. You can [try it online](http://spacemacs.org) - hint: if the online demo does not load, refresh the page in your browser.